# Desempenho em banco de dados somático

Tags: mysql

Possuo um sistema em desenvolvimento mas ja estão utilizando em beta, esse sistema tem como foco especifico:

> 'controlar 100% das ações, ação por ação, sem perder nenhum histórico
> de como estava e como está agora'

Com isso eu acabei caindo em um problema chamado:

Banco de dados gigante em pouco tempo de uso.

Isso não atrapalha o desempenho do usuário operacional, pois o sistema possui o espelho com o estado atual e trabalha com base nele, mas pesa no desempenho dos usuários administradores pra verificar qualquer coisa que ele queira.

Exemplo de dado:

```
ID    | COD          | DATETIME            |ACT                                       |USER_RELACIONATED                  | OBJECT_RELACIONATED | SECTOR                      |  SPEC
13869 |59d2677049ed6 | 2017-10-02 13:21:04 |NULL|TO|12094190345951120286cf02.53535322 | 12094190345951120286cf02.53535322 | 59ca9dbd11ee4       | contabil_control_obligation | deal_responsible
```

O uso do beta está mais ou menos um mês, e ja tenho 13896 registros somente no histórico do setor do controle de obrigações contábeis( atualmente tenho 9 setores), total de +- 90 mil registros.

O banco é dividido em duas partições o espelho, que é o que é exibido o usuário, e somático, que onde é armazenada as situações ação por ação, eu tomei todas as precauções que eu sabia pra formatar corretamente, definir os tipos de dados, definir indices, mas o problema está no tamanho desse banco.

Eu nunca trabalhei com um banco que fosse pesar tanto, a dúvida que eu estou tendo é a seguinte:

> 1 - Quais os conceitos mais aplicados em bancos de dados grandes ?
>
> 2 - Quais são os formatos de dados mais leves que podem ser usados para os campos ?
>
> 3 - Triggers e relações diretas vão atrapalhar meu desempenho quando
> eu estiver usando a tabela sem as relações e sem ativar o trigger ?

PS: Vai ficar realmente muito grande, previsão de quase 1M de registros anuais somente no histórico, e somente com o que está funcional atualmente na versão beta, é pra ser assim mesmo, o foco é esse, mas quero melhorar o consumo/ocupação disso de alguma forma.

PS2: Trocar de BD é uma opção.

Comment: Termos para pesquisar não faz parte do escopo do site. O que fazer depende muito do que precisa, tem várias soluções, mas só com estas informações não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com mais informações.